C# .NetMaui SignalR Chat App Messaging problem between users
I have created a chat app using SignalR. However, when I send a message, all clients receive it. But I want to enable messaging between two specific individuals. I want to test messaging between two emulators. Is there anyone who can help me with this?
using Microsoft.Maui.Devices;
using Microsoft.Maui.Media;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Media;
using Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;

namespace SignalRClient
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly HubConnection hubConnection;
        private IEnumerable<Locale> locales;
        private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string baseUrl = DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ? "http://10.0.2.2" : "http://localhost";
            hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl($"{baseUrl}:5127/chatHub")
                .Build();

            hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
            {
                this.Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(() =>
                {
                    lblChat.Text += $"<b>{user}</b>: {message}<br/>";
                });
            });

            _ = ConnectToHubAsync();
            cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            locales = await TextToSpeech.GetLocalesAsync();

            foreach (var locale in locales)
            {
                Languages.Items.Add(locale.Language);
            }
            Languages.SelectedIndex = 10;
            Languages.IsVisible = true;

            await FirstStartListening(); // Yeni eklenen çağrı
        }

        private async Task ConnectToHubAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await hubConnection.StartAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error connecting to Hub: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private async Task StartListening()
        {
            var isGranted = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();
            if (isGranted != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                isGranted = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();
            }

            if (isGranted == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
                cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

                try
                {
                    UpdateUI("Ses tanıma başlatılıyor...");

                    var recognitionResult = await SpeechToText.Default.ListenAsync(
                        cultureInfo,
                        new Progress<string>(partialText => UpdateUI(partialText)),
                        cancellationToken);

                    if (recognitionResult != null && recognitionResult.IsSuccessful)
                    {
                        var usertext = recognitionResult.Text.ToLowerInvariant();

                        this.Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(() =>
                        {
                            txtMessage.Text = usertext; // Tanınan metni "Enter your message" alanına yazdır
                        });

                        if (usertext.Contains("sesli mesaj gönder"))
                        {
                            btnRecord_Clicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                        }
                        else if (usertext.Contains("mesaj gönder"))
                        {
                            btnSend_Clicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        UpdateUI("Tekrar dene.");
                    }
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    UpdateUI("Ses tanıma iptal edildi.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    UpdateUI($"Hata: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateUI("Mikrofon izni verilmedi.");
            }
        }

        private void UpdateUI(string message)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(() =>
            {
                txtMessage.Text = message;
            });
        }

        private async void btnSend_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await SendAndSpeakAsync();
        }

        private async Task SendAndSpeakAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendMessageToAll", txtUsername.Text, txtMessage.Text);

                if (Languages.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                {
                    var selectedLocale = locales.ElementAt(Languages.SelectedIndex);
                    await TextToSpeech.SpeakAsync(txtMessage.Text, new SpeechOptions { Locale = selectedLocale });
                }

                txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error sending message: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private async Task FirstStartListening()
        {
            var isGranted = await CheckAndRequestMicrophonePermission();
            if (!isGranted)
            {
                UpdateUI("Mikrofon izni verilmedi.");
                return;
            }

            var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");

            while (true)
            {
                if (cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    break;
                }

                var recognitionResult = await SpeechToText.Default.ListenAsync(
                    cultureInfo,
                    new Progress<string>(partialText => { }),
                    cancellationTokenSource.Token);

                if (recognitionResult.IsSuccessful)
                {
                    var usertext = recognitionResult.Text.ToLowerInvariant();

                      this.Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(() =>
                    {
                        txtMessage.Text = usertext; // Tanınan metni "Enter your message" alanına yazdır
                    });

                    if (usertext.Contains("sesli mesaj gönder"))
                    {
                        btnRecord_Clicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    }
                    else if (usertext.Contains("mesaj gönder")) 

                    {
                        btnSend_Clicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task<bool> CheckAndRequestMicrophonePermission()
        {
            var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();
            }

            return status == PermissionStatus.Granted;
        }

        // Ses kaydı butonu için tıklama olayı
        private async void btnRecord_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
            cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            await StartListening();
        }
    }
}

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace SignalRServer.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessageToAll(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
}


using SignalRServer.Hubs;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddSignalR();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}


app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=ChatDemo}/{id?}");

app.Run();

I tried a few ways but could never do it. I tried with the connection ID but encountered errors.

There are many existing questions on this topic.  What have you tried?  Can you be more specific than “encountered error”?

I tried to manage connection IDs. Each user would have a connection ID assigned to them using a dictionary. Then I was going to add users to groups, but I couldn't do it. I couldn't write the code, to be more precise. @Jason

Can I also do this job without using a database? @Jason

You're using Clients.All.SendAsync, which will send a message to all connected clients. The method you need to be using is Clients.Client("connectionId").SendAsync to send the message to a specific connectionId, or Clients.User("userId").SendAsync to send to a user.
